# Laravel Dusk unexpected database refresh

Tags: laravel-dusk

**What do I have:**
Laravel: 5.7.28
PHP: 7.2
Homestead: 8.0.2

Test class:

```php
class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testExample()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create(/**/);

        $faker = Factory::create();

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->loginAs($user)
                ->visit(/**/)
                ->type(/**/)
                ->press(/**/)
                ->assertRouteIs(/**/);
        });
    }

    public function testExample2() //identical to testExample
      {
        //...

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            //...
        }); // <-- Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.users' doesn't exist
    }
}
```

**Question:** why DB is refreshed(?) on `$this->browse()`?

I run some seeds before each test, but they're not related to `users` table directly.

```php
abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->seed(\RolesSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

```php
trait CreatesApplication
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        //...

        $this->clearCache();

        return $app;
    }

    protected function clearCache()
    {
        $commands = ['clear-compiled', 'cache:clear', 'view:clear', 'config:clear', 'route:clear'];

        foreach ($commands as $command) {
            Artisan::call($command);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine while having one test method per test class.

Comment: Please create a minimal failing application and upload it to GitHub.

Comment: As I have two tests in one class, probably 2nd is started *before* the database is refreshed after the 1st test is completed.